# Formula for Parallax effect

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I am creating a SpriteKit game with 3 layers (far, near, close) and I want these layers to move with different horizontal speeds as the characters runs. In fact, the character never moves from the center, the floor/background is the one that moves from the right to the left.

Is there a formula accepted as good for creating a parallax effect with a number of layers?

thanks

Comment: since you've only got 3 distances, just assign each a different speed compenstation factor. e.g. close = speed 1.0, near = speed 0.9, far = speed = 0.7

Comment: but is there a formula for any number of layers?

Comment: not really. the "farther" away something is, the slower it'd move from parallax. so as z->bigger, speed->0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can think about this as similar triangles problem. Imagine a point on the horizon, waaay out there in the back of your game. Assume that that point is H meters away from the screen, where H is a big number. You can choose this number to be whatever you want. As you change its value, the effect will change according. You'll have to play around with it to see what you like.

Assume that the speed for the first layer is 1 (or one times some constant). Then, the screen is moving at a speed of 1 and at a distance of H.

Now assume that each layer is x distance away from the previous layer towards the horizon. Again, like H, you can pick x to be whatever you want to give the desired effect, as long as x is small compared to H.

So, for example, the foreground will be a distance 0 from the screen, the first layer back will be x units away, the second layer will be 2x units away and so on.

Now we can do the similar triangles. The screen layer is a speed of 1 at a distance H from the horizon. The second layer back is at an unknown speed (y) at a distance H-x from the horizon. We know that:

```
H / 1 = (H - x) / y
```

Or solving for y:

```
y = (H - x) / H
```

for the first layer into the screen.

---

A more general formula is as follows:

```
speed(i) = ((H - ix) a) / H
```

Where:

- a - Speed of the foreground (screen) layer
- i - The layer we are calculating the speed for
- x - The distance each layer is into the screen from the last (change this to tune the parallax effect)
- H - The distance to the Horizon (must be larger then the number of layers times x. Change this to tune the parallax effect)

Comment: What is speed(i)? Is it the magnitude of the vector? If this is the case how do I define the vector? With SpriteKit we have speed in x and y directions, not to mention since it's a parallax effect it should appear as if it's getting closer, so there's also a scale factor. How do I translate this speed to those three dimensions?